# How to authenticate client app with azure AD oauth2 hosted on Azure Linux Virtual Machine?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I truly hope I can get some help on this.

I have one Linux Virtual Machine in Azure portal where it exposes few REST APIs. And i have list of client application registered in my Azure Active Directory. I want to authenticate the rest API using Active directory. Have any of you have ever implemented this ? i tried from  this post and seems to be not working : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: I am not very clear your scenario, why you need join VM to a DS?

Comment: Do you want to use Azure Active Directory to authenticate to your REST APIs on your Linux VM via OAuth 2.0/SAML? The link you provide describes how to join a Windows Server VM to a Azure Directory Domain Controller...and that is a totally different story.